# how to handle a dialog when the application is in background

Tags: android

I have an application which executes a long time task in an `AsyncTask.`
The result can be displayed in a `dialog`, and when this occurs while the application is in background, I get an `IllegalStateException!`

*** Edit ***

My Asynctask, execute Internet request. Normally it should take a so long time but, for a particular reason during my tests, it took a long time, so I put the app in background to see what's wrong with my Internet parameters. This is how I got in this situation, and I though such situation where a dialog is displayed while the app is in background could occur.

So, I should have precised that I effectively display this dialog in the postExecute method.

The excerpt of the code is:

```
static class InitTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {
    // Référence faible à l'activité
    private Fragment_init mActivity = null;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private DialogFragment dialog;
    private Site site = null;
    Context context = null;

    public InitTask (Fragment_init pActivity, Site pSite, FragmentManager _fragmentManager) {
        mActivity = pActivity;
        context = mActivity.getActivity();
        site = pSite;
        fragmentManager = _fragmentManager;
      }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute () {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute (Integer result) {
        mActivity = (Fragment_init) site.getFragmentActivity();
        if(result != 1) {
            String msg;

            dialog = new YesNoDialog();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("title", mActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.label_titleAlertInit));

            switch (result) {
            case -1: 
                msg = mActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.label_messageAlertCnfVDescFile);
                break;
            case nnn:
              ....
                break;
            default: 
                msg = mActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.label_messageAlertCnfUnknown);
                break;

            }
            args.putString("message", msg);
            args.putString("positiveButton", site.getMainActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.label_positiveBtnOk));
            dialog.setArguments(args);
            dialog.setTargetFragment(site.getFragmentActivity(), Site.MSG_ALERT_CONFIGURATION_ERROR);
            dialog.show(fragmentManager, "tag");  // I get the IllegalStateException here

  ......
```

How to deal with this situation?
Do I have to wait that the application comes back in foreground and if yes, how?

Regards,

Comment: Please post your code as well.

Comment: You can check in `onPause()` if it's not null and showing and cancel it if so. But, if it's a long task then you may want to use something else. `AsyncTask` isn't meant for that

Comment: you can not touch `UI thread` from `doInBackground()`.you can handle `dialog` in `onPreExecute()` , `onProgressUpdate()` and `onPostExecute()` for more details check this :http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/

Comment: @Rustam - I think he's talking about once the task completes. How does he handle notification on the UI thread when the app is in the background?

Comment: I realize that effectively didn't give enough informations so, sorry I edit my post, and thanks to Rustam for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to replace your `commit()` with `commitAllowingStateLoss()`. If the task finishes in the background it will attempt, and fail, to show your dialog but it will not throw the exception or cause a crash. The downside is that your dialog will never show up.

If you do want the dialog to show when the app reopens there are basically 2 paths you can take.

1) In your Activity's `onPause()` method you can cancel your AsyncTask. In your Activity's `onResume()` method you can relaunch your AsyncTask. This is often the best practice (as your Activity shouldn't be doing too much while it is not actively running). The downside is that your user will have to wait for the whole AsyncTask to complete all over again when they relaunch the Activity.

2) Use a couple of flags to signal when events should occur. Something like the following...

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private boolean mIsActive = false;
    private boolean mDialogPending = false;
    private YesNoDialog mDialog = null;

    ...

    public void showDialog(YesNoDialog dialog) {
        if (mIsActive) {
            // Our Activity is in the foreground, show normally
            dialog.show(...); // fill in FragmentManager etc
        } else {
            // Our Activity is in the background, we can't show yet
            mDialog = dialog;
            mDialogPending = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mIsActive = true;
        if (mDialogIsPending) {
            // Our dialog has been waiting for us to get back, show it now
            mDialogIsPending = false;
            mDialog.show(...); // fill in FragmentManager etc
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mIsActive = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid to not really understand you and anyway, I suppose that if created a dialog to inform about a result, good or bad, I would prefer that the user see it.

Comment: Currently they cannot see the dialog, and your app will crash. This change would prevent your app from crashing, that is all. A more complicated fix would be required to correctly show the dialog when the user reopens the app.

Comment: It sounds like you are hoping to show the dialog when your Activity resumes, so I have updated my answer with some suggestions.

Comment: Thanks xaevinx, I think I'm going to investigate to the 2nd path. As the AsyncTask download files from Internet, That's not very cool to cancel it to redownload after the same files or, even if it's possible to check what is downloaded already, to pause the transfer whereas it's a good think to be able to do that in background. I'm going to see that soon.